# How to configure a VPN server to be able to access the internal network such as the Internet?

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, nat, windows-server

I got a virtual machine, running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. The server has got a single network interface with a public IPv4 address (no IPv6) and is directly connected to the internet. It is providing a domain controller which I want to make accessible to several devices over the internet. For security reasons, I want to use a VPN connection for that. Therefore I already installed the Routing and Remote Access role. I used the custom configuration to provide VPN access, adopted the firewall settings and switched from DHCP to a static address poll (because I have no configured DHCP server). After that, all my devices were able to connect to the VPN server and could access the domain controller. The problem is that they cannot access the internet in parallel.

How can I change this? I searched a solution for days but every solution I found requires a second network adapter. I tried to add a second virtual internal adapter but this didn't work either (I have full access to the vm settings).

Edit (network settings):

```
Server:
Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : MYSERVER
   Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . : MYSERVER.EDV
   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Ja
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   DNS-Suffixsuchliste . . . . . . . : MYSERVER.EDV

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-00-87-18
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::316c:c971:f347:5320%6(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50352214
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-B5-04-92-00-50-56-00-87-18
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

PPP-Adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert
```

On the client side, I simply created a new VPN connection with my server's IP address.

Comment: "_How to configure a VPN server to be able to access the internal network such as the Internet?_" The Internet is an internal network? The Internet would be the very definition of an external network, not an internal network.

Comment: With internal network, I do mean my domain controller. Sorry if I did not express myself clear enough.

Comment: You need to configure routing properly.  Setting it up properly is extremely situation dependent, and you haven't really given us any information to work with.

Comment: I posted my ipconfig /all output. Do you need anything else?

Comment: The output of `route print` could help. It's likely that your AD/VPN is used the default route instead of your internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. I simply had to install the routing server role as well. Subsequently I was able to enable NAT for my external network adapter using the RRAS MMC Snap-in.